# Error Mocking a @Value annotation in Spring boot

Tags: java, junit, mockito

This is my class :

```
public class Foo {

    @Value("${myapp.foo}")
    private String foo;

    void fooValue(){
       // some code
    }
}
```

This is my test class :

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class FooTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private Foo foo;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(foo, "myappfoo", "foo");
    }

    @Test
    public void testFoo() {
        // some test code
    }
}
```

When I am running the test I get the below error :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find field 'myapp.foo' of type [null] on target object [Foo@18271936] or target class [class Foo]
    at org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils.setField(ReflectionTestUtils.java:185)
    at org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils.setField(ReflectionTestUtils.java:120)
```

Also I want to use the string variable foo in my test method. How to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ReflectionTestUtils](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/util/ReflectionTestUtils.html#setField-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) receive the second parameter as the field name, you can just directly code

```
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(foo, "foo", "foo");
```

the first argument is the target, second is field name, the third is the value

Comment: Thanks ! And how to use the field name string variable `foo` in the test nethod ?

Comment: use the ReflectionTestUtils.getField(foo, "foo") method, you need to cast it since it returns Object. The first param is the target and the second is the field name. @Som